# How to set the size of the panel in wx python

Tags: wxpython

I am very new to wxPython and facing a problem as given below.

I need to have 2 panels horizontaly inside a frame.

As of now I can put 2 panels in the frame using a box sizer. In one panel I have an image displayed and in other panel I have some controls like text ctrl or check box and stuff.

But when I resize the frame, the panels get resized wierdly. As I resize the frame, the image panel becomes smaller and smaller and starts moving towards the left hand corner and ultimately turns into a small dot on the left hand corner.

Please run my code to see what happens when the frame is resized.

I need help regarding this...

Please reply......

Thanks.

Damodar

Here is my code.

```
import wx

class ImagePanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self,parent,id,title,imagePath):            
        #=========================================================
        # Create a panel
        #=========================================================
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,id,style=wx.BORDER_THEME)

        #==========================================================
        # Display the .png image in the panel
        #==========================================================
        png = wx.Image(imagePath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap() 
        wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, (0, 0), (png.GetWidth(),png.GetHeight()))

class ControlPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        #=========================================================
        # Create a panel
        #=========================================================
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,id,size=(200,700),style=wx.BORDER_THEME)
        cb1 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Option 1")
        cb2 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Option 2")
        cb3 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Option 3")
        cb4 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Option 4")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.AddSpacer(5,5)
        sizer.Add(cb1)
        sizer.AddSpacer(5,5)
        sizer.Add(cb2)
        sizer.AddSpacer(5,5)
        sizer.Add(cb3)
        sizer.AddSpacer(5,5)
        sizer.Add(cb4)
        sizer.AddSpacer(5,5)            
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        #==========================================================
        # Shows the text control in the panel
        #==========================================================
        #wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,"This is a multiline text editor.")

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = wx.Frame(None,-1,"Main Frame",size=(900,700),
             style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
box.Add(ImagePanel(frame,1,"Panel A","Artifacts_vs_Elaborations_36855.png"))
box.AddSpacer(5,5)
box.Add(ControlPanel(frame,2,"Panel B"))
frame.SetSizer(box)
frame.Show(1)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I have posted the code on top. Please reply.

Thanks
Damodar

Comment: I have pasted the revised code. Also I have rephrased my question.

Please reply

Thanks

Damodar

Comment: FYI: There is an official wxPython mailing list / Google group that you might find helpful as well: http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was wrong with my code. I was not handling the resize event i.e. EVT_RESIZE. Now it is working fine.

Thanks

Damodar